# Why with apache-http-client at some point our Https calls are treated as calls without DNS name, but with IP address?

Tags: java, ssl, kubernetes-ingress, sni, ssl-handshake

We have a problem with doing a handshake for the certificate like

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <g.i.t.n.c.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.t.n.c.com]
```

Our ingress is configured to provide a certificate with alternative name `g.i.t.n.c.com` if we access it through DNS name and `*.t.n.c.com` if we access through the IP.

But in our code we just have a `Spring WS` client using `Apache Http Client` under the hood.

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <g.i.t.n.c.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.t.n.c.com]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:507)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:437)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsConnection.onSendAfterWrite(HttpComponentsConnection.java:121)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:48)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:658)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:606)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
```

And for unknown reason that started happening at some time, and at some time it was ok and `SslSocket` was established retrieving the right certificate (like it was accessing our `Ingress` via `DNS` hostname with `SNI` hostname data) and at some point (causing the above exception) the call for establishing connection was using IP without `DNS hostname` and no `SNI` data, and we got the broken certificate that appears only if our ingress is accessed without `DNS name` in `SNI`.

To get `SNI` details (`ClientHello` message) you may run Java app with

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose:keymanager:trustmanager
```

And you will have extra loggin to `std.out` like

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|02 14|XNIO-1 task-9|2023-09-04 12:48:06.626 MSK|Finished.java:860|Consuming server Finished handshake message (
```

How to force it to use only one way to connect, using the DNS name at any time?

We use Java 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8220723 this was the root cause of the problem

To work it around we forced the TLS1.2 to work to avoid using TLS1.3 through

adding

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

or

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```